# Android: Images not visible in gallery after download

Tags: android

I wonder if anyone can please shed some light on the following problem.

I am downloading images from a web site to a specific folder on my mobile Android device (HTC Desire HD). The images download perfectly (I see this using ES Explorer). They are not corrupt as I can view the images.

When my app uses a Gallery control to view the images, the Gallery is blank !!!

After playing around for some time I found that if I unmount the SD card and then remount it the images are displayed in the Gallery control.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: if u found your answer then please let me know about this i also have same prob at :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934299/gallery-item-is-not-updated-while-file-downloading

Answer (score 4):

I try this and it worked for me..hope it help others..

```
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { f.getAbsolutePath()},
            null,
 new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

After downloading file from web just send broadcast to your device MediaScanner,

Send broadcast to **MediaScannerConnection** in your device like,

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Actually, In android device gallery application scan all media files at when Remounted SDcard or at time of Reboot your device. For your requirement you have to do it manually by your code.

Comment: This search for all the images. And it involves a lot of unnecessary data processing that may be irrelevant when we have just single image to be shown up in gallery.

Comment: it worked but my issue is when i download first image and restart my device..it shows..and when again i download second image it does not show..even i restart my device so many times..but yet second image is not showing..

Comment: @Johnson - Is your image file is exist in storage?

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have given permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in your manifest file.

This will not allow your application to write images on sd card,if this is not a case than another problem might be that u do not have folder of exist in sd card.

Comment: FYI He has that permission since he can see the downloaded file FE. So your both answers does not relate to the question asked. Implementing MediaScanner would be the right way.