# Gallery item is not updated while file downloading

Tags: android, download, android-videoview, android-gallery

I am downloading a video from my application but that video is not currently show in gallery, Now i just restart my device and then it shows in gallery item. I don't understand why, Is any video tag set with the file which will tell android to add this item in gallery video.

This is my code

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                long total = 0;
                int len = 0;

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

                while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    if(!cancel)
                    {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                        // send update
                        total = total + len;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File f = new File(filePath);

                        System.out.println("Path is=========="+f.getAbsolutePath());

                        if(f.exists())
                            f.delete();

                        cancel = false;             

                        break;
                    }
                }
```

please help, thanks in advance

Comment: post your code, so we can help for it... probably you are not setting the downlaoded item to gallery, which you are doing initially

Comment: see my code in my edited qus

Comment: its worknig fine when u restarts right? It means no problem with your downlaoding, bt problem with setting data to gallery adapter as soon as downloaded... So check it once

Comment: dude when other application download this same file then it imminently reflect in gallery item

Comment: but hw come another app will come to know the exaxt URl which you are downlaoding???

Comment: i try with g cloud application take back up of same pic and delete from sdcard now restore and this will automatically add in galley that time only no need to reboot device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohk i found my own question's answer just add this below line whenever download will have been completed

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))));
```

Comment: it worked but my issue is when i download first image and restart my device..it shows..and when again i download second image it does not show..even i restart my device so many times..but yet second image is not showing..

Comment: from my this above line i just refresh my path to find file dude so every time after download u just refresh your path as u did in first time

Comment: This is giving me error `Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` @Bhanu Sharma

Comment: give permission MEDIA_MOUNTED in mainfeast

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it worked..hope it help others too.

```
   MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { f.getAbsolutePath()},
            null,
 new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

    }
    });
```